Pinched negative curvature and Gromov hyperbolicity
I would like to show that if a complete, simply connected Riemannian manifold $M$ satisfies $sec\leq\delta$ for some $\delta<0$, then it is Gromov-hyperbolic. Here $sec$ denotes the sectional curvature of $M$.
I was trying an approach based on Rauch's comparison theorem, as formulated in Proposition 2.5 of Chapter 10 in Riemannian Geometry, do Carmo, 1992. Then I realised that this attempt looks ill-informed, because Rauch's comparison theorem gives an inequality on the length of curves in the direction opposite to the one I desire.
After a research in the literature, I found no evidence suggesting the truth of this result which I thought almost self-evident in the beginning.
Therefore I ask: is my pseudo-theorem true? Is there a way to prove it without getting involved with the much more general theory of $\mathrm{CAT}(k)$ spaces?
Edit: If one wants to use the theory of $\mathrm{CAT}(k)$ spaces, in Theorem 1A.6, Chapter II of Metric spaces of non positive curvature by Bridson and Haefliger, 1999, it is proved that a Riemannian manifold $M$ has sectional curvature bounded above by a given constant $\kappa$ if and only if it is a locally $\mathrm{CAT}(k)$ space. Can one promote this local statement to a global one when $M$ is simply connected?

Can you recall what is Gromov-Hyperbolic?

A metric space (not necessarily geodesic) is Gromov-hyperbolic when all geodesic triangles are $\delta$-thin for some fixed $\delta>0$, that is every point on any side lies in a $\delta$-neighbourhood of the union of the other two sides. Think of triangles in the usual hyperbolic space for a tangible example.

It is not a "pseudotheorem" but a theorem. Unfortunately, Bridson and Haefliger formulated results in the Appendix a suboptimal way, which forces one to read their proofs (which you should do). The key is that (for $\kappa\le 0)$ in Lemma 1A.5 one can take $\epsilon=\infty$ and $V=M$ (Cartan-Hadamard theorem). Why did they chose to hide this fact (since their main interest is the case $\kappa\le 0$) is a mystery.

One way to argue is to combine Theorem 1A.6, Chapter II in Bridson and Haefliger with Cartan-Hadamard theorem 4.1 in Chapter II.4. The latter establishes that a complete simply connected space of curvature $\le k$ is a $CAT(k)$ space, provided that $k\le 0$.
